# UNLocationNotificationTrigger not notifying users in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, notifications, geofencing

I am creating a program that notifies the user when they enter a specified location. The code looks correct for me, but I cannot get it to actually display a notification. It does work when I change the trigger to be UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger, but that only notifies a user based on a specified time limit, not location. Below is my code, and I was hoping somebody could offer me guidance or point me to other resources that can explain why this issue is occurring.

I am quite new to iOS programming, so I greatly appreciate it! :)

```
import SwiftUI
import UserNotifications
import CoreLocation
struct ContentView: View {
    
    private let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button(action: {
                       self.locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
                      
                   }) {
                       Text("Request authorization")
                   }
            Button("Request Permission") {
                UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .badge, .sound]) { success, error in
                    if success {
                        print("All set!")
                    } else if let error = error {
                        print(error.localizedDescription)
                    }
                }
            }

            Button("Notify when arrived at location") {
               
                let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
                content.title = "Feed the cat"
                content.subtitle = "It looks hungry"
                content.sound = UNNotificationSound.default
                
               //sets geofence
                let center = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 37.7861353, longitude: -122.4532538)
                
                let region = CLCircularRegion(center: center, radius: 2000.0, identifier: "Headquarters")
                region.notifyOnEntry = true //notify user when they enter
                region.notifyOnExit = false //do not notify when they exit
                
                //when user enters, trigger notification
                let trigger = UNLocationNotificationTrigger(region: region, repeats: false)

               //  choose a random identifier
                let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: UUID().uuidString, content: content, trigger: trigger)
                
               print("waiting to enter location")

                // add our notification request
                UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request)

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Make sure to put your app in background to get the notification

Comment: set UNUserNotificationCenter delegate

Comment: @LeoDabus Thank you for your response! I have tried doing it with the app in the background, and I am getting the same result with no notifications. Do you have any other suggestions?